# Create and Consume Collections in solr4

Tags: alfresco, solr4, alfresco-webscripts

Someone suggest me to create multiple collections in solr (lucene) to get faster response from the solr.I am new in this era so can anyone please help me how to create collections in solr and how alfresco can consume those collections.

Note- i am using solr4 and alfresco.5.2

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, even if Alfresco is using SolR, you don't have the access to all the functionnalities. I don't think that creating multiple collections is possible in the Alfresco product.

The closest thing to what you are talking about is sharding which enables you to split your index in smaller ones to improve performance : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/solr-shard-config.html.

The documentation explains well the mecanism, you have the choice between [manual](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/solr-hash-shard.html) or [dynamic](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dynamic-sharding.html) sharding.

Finally, if you are looking for better performances, [alfresco replication](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/solr-replication.html) is another lever to improve you alfresco responsness.